# background color and font Family in editext should change when buttons are been clicked

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext

I am trying to create an activity which contain an edittext, of which background color and fonts should be changed whenever the button is been clicked.
To perform these actions on the edittext, I have created two ArrayList of int value and saved all the color's id and the font's id in this ArrayList. whenever the button is clicked the background color didn't change but the color's Hexa code print in the edittext and these color codes comes with extra ff values in front of every color's code like #ff1EFA9D and in the font method I am getting an error that says:-

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nanb.alpha/com.nanb.alpha.postcreater}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1

I have tried to find the solution over the internet but didn't get any solution that satisfies the error.

code For changing the background color and font of the edittext is given below

```
  private EditText editText;
  private ImageButton color,font;
  ArrayList<Integer> bgcolorlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
  ArrayList<Integer> fontstyle = new ArrayList<Integer>(6);
  int fontstylename=R.font.abril_fatface,bgcolor=R.color.white,fontpostion = fontstyle.indexOf(fontstylename);
  int postion = bgcolorlist.indexOf(bgcolor);


 private void Initialization() {
    cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    createnextbutton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
    editText = view.findViewById(R.id.textpost);
    color = view.findViewById(R.id.bgcolorbutton);
    font = view.findViewById(R.id.fontstyle);
}

 //codes are for the background color changing
  private void backgroundcolormethod() {

    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.white);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.darkGreen);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.colorAccent);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.colorPrimary);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.orange);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg5);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg4);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg3);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg2);
    bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg1);

    editText.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);

    color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(postion == 10){
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"last element",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editText.setText(bgcolorlist.get(postion));
                postion = 0;
            }else{
                int newpostion = postion + 1;
                editText.setText(bgcolorlist.get(newpostion));
                postion = newpostion;
            }
        }
    });

}

//codes for changing the fonts 
private void fontstylemethod() {
    fontstyle.add(R.font.abril_fatface);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.cedarville_cursive);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.alfa_slab_one);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.annie_use_your_telescope);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.aclonica);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.aguafina_script);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.arizonia);

    editText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(fontpostion));

    font.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fontpostion == 6){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"last element",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editText.setText(fontstyle.get(postion));
                fontpostion= 0;
            }else{
                int newpostion = fontpostion + 1;
                editText.setText(fontstyle.get(newpostion));
                fontpostion = newpostion;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Help me to solve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your codes to this:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> bgcolorlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(11);
  ArrayList<Integer> fontstyle = new ArrayList<Integer>(7);
  int fontpostion = 0;
  int postion = 0;


 private void Initialization() {
    cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    createnextbutton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
    editText = view.findViewById(R.id.textpost);
    color = view.findViewById(R.id.bgcolorbutton);
    font = view.findViewById(R.id.fontstyle);
}

//codes are for the background color changing
private void backgroundcolormethod() {

  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.white);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.darkGreen);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.colorAccent);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.colorPrimary);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.orange);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg5);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg4);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg3);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg2);
  bgcolorlist.add(R.color.edittextbg1);

  editText.setBackgroundColor(bgcolorlist.get(0));

  color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(postion == 10){
            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"last element",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editText.setText(bgcolorlist.get(postion));
            postion = 0;
        }else{
            postion++;
            editText.setText(bgcolorlist.get(postion));
        }
    }
});

}

//codes for changing the fonts 
private void fontstylemethod() {
    fontstyle.add(R.font.abril_fatface);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.cedarville_cursive);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.alfa_slab_one);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.annie_use_your_telescope);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.aclonica);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.aguafina_script);
    fontstyle.add(R.font.arizonia);

    editText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(fontstyle.get(0)));

    font.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fontpostion == 6){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"last element",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editText.setText(fontstyle.get(postion));
                fontpostion= 0;
            }else{
                fontpostion++;
                editText.setText(fontstyle.get(fontpostion));
            }
        }
    });
}
```